# Can there be a metric space where no contraction has a fixed point?

Tags: soft-question, metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems, newton-raphson, banach-fixed-point

We know that:

**If $X$ is a metric space, then every contraction *has at most* one fixed point.**

(Note: if metric space is complete, then we have existence and uniqueness)

I wonder if there can be a metric space for which no contraction has a fixed point. Thanks.

Comment: That can't be right: take the rationals and $f (x)=x/2+1/x $.

Comment: What you say we know is false: consider the metric space $X=\{2^{-n}:n\in\mathbb N\}$, with the metric induced from $\mathbb R$, wih the map $x\mapsto x/2$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Sorry I mixed up "least" and "most"

Comment: If it is a complete metric space then by the Banach fixed-point theorem then every contraction must have at least one fixed point.

Comment: You need to define what do you mean by a contraction since there are different definitions. Also, consider only nonconstant contractions and require $X$ to contain more than one point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $X$ is non-empty then we can choose some $x_0\in X$ and define $f(x)=x_0$ for all $x\in X$. This is a contraction with a fixed point.

Comment: The question is looking for a metric space which lacks fixed points on contractions.  This answer gives a contraction with a fixed point.

Comment: @QthePlatypus: and therefore shows that no such metric space exists.

Comment: You might wish to clarify that you are presenting a counter example.